# Speeding up unpacking of encrypted image file in python

Tags: python, numba, jit, pypy

I am currently unpacking an encrypted file from the software I use to get an image (2048x2048) from a file (along with other information).  I'm currently able to do this but it takes about 1.7 seconds to load.  Normally this would be fine but I'm loading 40ish images at each iteration and my next step in this simulation is to add more iterations.  I've been trying to use JIT interpreters like pypy and numba.  The code below is just one function in a larger object but it's where I'm having the most timelag.

Pypy works but when I call my numpy functions, it takes twice as long.  So I tried using numba, but it doesn't seem to like unpack.  I tried using numba within pypy, but that also seems to not work.  My code goes a bit like this

```py
from struct import unpack
import numpy as np

def read_file(filename: str, nx: int, ny: int) -> tuple:
    f = open(filename, "rb")
    raw = [unpack('d', f.read(8))[0] for _ in range(2*nx*ny)] #Creates 1D list

    real_image = np.asarray(raw[0::2]).reshape(nx,ny) #Every other point is the real part of the image
    imaginary_image = np.asarray(raw[1::2]).reshape(nx,ny) #Every other point +1 is imaginary part of image

    return real_image, imaginary_image
```

In my normal python interpreter, the `raw` line takes about 1.7 seconds and the rest are <0.5 seconds.
If I comment out the numpy lines and just unpack in pypy, the `raw` operation takes about 0.3 seconds.  However, if I perform the the reshaping operations, it takes a lot longer (I know it has to do with fact that numpy is optimized in C and will take longer to convert).

So I just discovered numba and thought I'd give it a try by going back to my normal python interpreter (CPython?).  If I add the `@njit` or `@vectorize` decorators to the function I get the following error message

```py
File c:\Users\MyName\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py:468, in _DispatcherBase._compile_for_args(self, *args, **kws)
    464         msg = (f"{str(e).rstrip()} \n\nThis error may have been caused "
    465                f"by the following argument(s):\n{args_str}\n")
    466         e.patch_message(msg)
--> 468     error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
    469 except errors.UnsupportedError as e:
    470     # Something unsupported is present in the user code, add help info
    471     error_rewrite(e, 'unsupported_error')

File c:\Users\MyName\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py:409, in _DispatcherBase._compile_for_args.<locals>.error_rewrite(e, issue_type)
    407     raise e
    408 else:
--> 409     raise e.with_traceback(None)

TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'unpack': Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```

I may be reading this error message wrong but it seems that Numba does not like built in functions?
I haven't looked into any of the other options like Cython.  Is there some way to make Numba or pypy work?  I'm mostly interested in speeding this operation up so I'd be very interested to know what people think is the best option.  I'd be willing to explore optmizing in C++ but I'm not aware of how to link the two

Comment: I guess the majority of time is spent on reading the file from disk. Maybe the `unpack()` isn't needed and you can use [`numpy.memmap`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) directly on the file.

Comment: Where's the encryption?

Comment: Reading the file 8 bytes at a time is certainly not the most efficient way.  Try something like `raw = unpack('d' * (2*nx*ny), f.read())` to do the whole thing in one piece.

Comment: @KellyBundy, the encryption is provided by the software documentation I'm using

Comment: @jasonharper, I think that's the answer!  It's about on the level of I was expecting to get out of pypy.  I timed it at 0.308 seconds which is a lot better than my 1.6 seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issuing tons of `.read(8)` calls and many small `unpack`ings is dramatically increasing your overhead, with limited benefit. If you weren't using `numpy` already, I'd point you to preconstructing an instance of `struct.Struct` and/or using `.iter_unpack` to dramatically reduce the costs of looking up `Struct`s to use for unpacking, and replacing a bunch of tiny `read` calls with a bulk `read` (you need all the data in memory anyway), but since you're using `numpy`, you can have it do all the work for you much more easily:

```
import numpy as np

def read_file(filename: str, nx: int, ny: int) -> tuple:
    data_needed = 2*8*nx*ny
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:  # Use with statements so you don't risk leaking file handles
        raw = f.read(data_needed)  # Perform a single bulk read
    if len(raw) != data_needed:
        raise ValueError(f"{filename!r} is too small to contain a {nx}x{ny} image")
    arr = np.frombuffer(raw)  # Convert from raw buffer to a single numpy array
    real_image = arr[::2].reshape(nx,ny)  # Slice and reshape to desired format
    imaginary_image = arr[1::2].reshape(nx,ny)
    return real_image, imaginary_image
```

That replaces a bunch of relatively slow Python level manipulation with a *very* fast:

1. Bulk read of all the data
2. Bulk conversion of the data to a single `numpy` array (it doesn't even unpack it properly, it just interprets it in-place as being of the expected type, which defaults to "float", actually C `double`s)
3. Slicing and reshaping appropriately

No need for `numba`; on my local box, for a 2048x2048 call, your code took ~1.75 seconds, this version took ~10 *milliseconds*.

Comment: I've been using numpy for a bunch of other things but this is the first I'm seeing it here.  So thank you!  I do like this approach, but I have a bunch of header information ~19 header infos and two blank lines and some are different byte sizes.   Is the different byte size an issue?  I'm guessing after a bulk read I can just sparse the data accordingly?  i.e `version = arr[0], nx = arr[1], ny = arr[2]` etc.

Comment: Nevermind.  I figured it out thanks to your post.  With the extra reading I got my code segment from 1.7 seconds to 30 milliseconds!  For the first few header segments that were integers, I ran `header_ints = f.read(36) #first 36 bytes; header_int_info = np.frombuffer(header_ints, dtype='int')` then parsed the data

Answer (score 1):

Here is one version with `np.memmap` - the reading on my system with plenty of RAM and nvme drive takes `0.00012` sec (but maybe the system has cached the file in memory, so test it on your setup).

```py
import numpy as np


def create_test_binary_file(filename, nx=2048, ny=2048):
    arr = np.zeros(shape=2 * nx * ny, dtype=np.float64)
    arr[::2] = 1
    arr[1::2] = 2

    with open(filename, "wb") as f_out:
        f_out.write(arr.tobytes())


def read_file(filename, nx=2048, ny=2048):
    arr = np.memmap(filename, dtype=np.float64, mode="r", shape=2 * nx * ny)

    return arr[::2].reshape(nx, ny), arr[1::2].reshape(nx, ny)


create_test_binary_file("test.dat")

r, i = read_file("test.dat")
print(r, i, sep="\n\n")
```

Prints:

```
[[1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
 ...
 [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]]

[[2. 2. 2. ... 2. 2. 2.]
 [2. 2. 2. ... 2. 2. 2.]
 [2. 2. 2. ... 2. 2. 2.]
 ...
 [2. 2. 2. ... 2. 2. 2.]
 [2. 2. 2. ... 2. 2. 2.]
 [2. 2. 2. ... 2. 2. 2.]]
```

Comment: Oh, neat, missed `np.memmap` (I'd actually written mine to use `mmap.mmap`, but decided it wasn't doing much of anything in that case since I couldn't leave the `mmap` live, so it needed to be copied anyway). Guessing `np.memmap` is managing the underlying memory mapping for you, so it does what you'd hope. +1 from me.

Comment: Oh nice, I'll look into that.  But what I'm not sure of is that I can't load the whole file like that.  I have a lot of other header information.  About 19 other single 8 bit values I need to read before the actual image.  Is there a way to do that here?